# robot localizaton pkg for ros2

Tags: navigation, ros2, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is their any robot localization package for ros2 available? I searched but only found some discussions in ros discuss but couldn't find the exact github package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360933/robot-localizaton-pkg-for-ros2/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its been ported since Crystal. Its at the same address as before in the eloquent branch.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1